# Detect back event on android keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have some intents inside a tab controller and for one of them I have an edit text which I need to know for sure when it has focus and when it loses this focus.
I have mapped most of the events like focus listener, OnEditorActionListener and so on, now my only problem that remains is that when I have focus the soft keyboard appears and I want to close it either:
1) by the done button and not by the back button on the phone (disable back button to close keyboard while the keyboard is visible)
2) detect the back button event while the keyboard is visible so that I can pass the focus to some other control.

I have tried multiple ways, but with no success, like onBackPressed, onConfigurationChanged (add hiddenKeyboard in the manifest), key_down on activity and so on, but no success.

Does anybody succeded this? Practically I want when the keyboard is visible and I press back on phone, my edit text to lose focus (otherControl.requestFocus -> which is a relative layout).

Comment: show me what have you tried so far

Comment: 1. this one

txtSearchBar.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() 
     {         
         public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) 
         {
             if (event.getKeyCode() == KEYCODE_BACK) 
             {
              layoutFocus.requestFocus();                   
             }
             return false;
         }
     });

2. method 2 on onBackPressed, layoutFocus.requestFocus();

3. add hiddenKeyboard in the manifest for this activity and put

 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)

Comment: Can't add more code as I cannot answer to my question if I have more than 100 points reputation :)

Comment: you can edit your question and post code there only

Comment: @Catalin: u r trying to hijack native android user experience, there  is a way but, users wont like this behaviour of ur app honestly

Comment: Hello no... the idea is that I have a layout that I want to animate when an edit text has focus and when it loses it, that's the only thing and I cannot complete this because of the back key which normally hides the keyboard, but doesn't loose the focus of the control that's all. Maybe you know another workaround this.

Answer (score 13):

Old topic, but here is the expected answer

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "BACK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
}
```

You should put this in a class that overrides EditText (class MyEditText extends EditText...)

Answer (score 7):

Here is the way to capture back press key event: 1. Extent editText view to override onKeyPreIme

```
package com.test.test;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * Created by sumit.saurabh on 11/10/16.
 */

public class ChatEditText extends EditText
{
    /* Must use this constructor in order for the layout files to instantiate the class properly */
    public ChatEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private KeyImeChange keyImeChangeListener;

    public void setKeyImeChangeListener(KeyImeChange listener)
    {
        keyImeChangeListener = listener;
    }

    public interface KeyImeChange
    {
        public void onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyImeChangeListener != null)
        {
            keyImeChangeListener.onKeyIme(keyCode, event);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

2. ChatEditText in xml

```
<com.test.test.ChatEditText
    android:id = "@+id/messageEditText"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity = "bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft = "12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight = "30dp"
    android:background = "@null"
    android:hint = "Type your message"
    android:inputType = "textMultiLine"
    android:singleLine = "false"
    android:textColorHint = "#c4c0bd"
    android:textSize = "18sp"/>
```

3. Then attach a listener from anywhere like so:

```
 private ChatEditText messageEditText;
    messageEditText =
       (ChatEditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
messageEditText.setKeyImeChangeListener(new ChatEditText.KeyImeChange(){
    @Override
    public void onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK == event.getKeyCode())
        {
            // do something
        }
    }});
```

Answer (score 3):

here it is

```
 @Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
      if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
     {  //do you back event work here
           }    
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but it is not working unfortunately :( Using your method the back key is trapped only when the soft keyboard is already hidden (after I have pressed on the Done button) and then it goes out of the program. When the keyboard is shown and I press on back, it executes the keyboard hide, but doesn't go through this method. I am testing on android 2.2 and 2.3

Comment: Yes because when u press back and the keyboard is up, only keyboard activity listen that, and it goes back, you can listen back event if and only if user press back on your activity, in this case keyboard activity listen this back event..

Comment: Any way to track the back from the keyboard activity? or any way to disable the back button to work while the keyboard is up? Something like subclassing an edit text and changing some things? is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can block native keyboard, create your own custom soft keyboard, and do whatever you want on back key press. it is not that complex but some tricky.. I know it can be done. do some googlling on custom keyboard you can get it done.